# How to get indices list for rows starting with lower case letter?

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a dataframe with one of the columns being df['Names']. How can I locate all the rows whose names start with a lower case letter?

```
col1     Names  
1564      abby   
2289      Barry
```

etc.

I'm trying to accomplish this using regex with no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

one way from `str.lower`

```
df[df.Names.str[0]==df.Names.str[0].str.lower()]
Out[173]: 
   col1 Names
0  1564  abby
```

Another way `islower`

```
df[df.Names.str[0].str.islower()]
Out[174]: 
   col1 Names
0  1564  abby
```

Comment: Problem with `islower` is that it returns `True` only when all char are lower, not only the first one

Comment: Correct, this should really be `df[df.col.str[0].str.islower()]` Took the liberty of editing that in.

Answer (score 2):

One way using `string.ascii_lowercase`

```
import string
df.loc[df.Names.str[0].isin(list(string.ascii_lowercase))]
```

Another way using `regex`

```
df[df.col.str.match('[a-z].*')]
```

Some timings

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': ['abc', 'Abc', 'dce', 'ADAE']})
df = pd.concat([df]*100)

%%timeit 
a = df['col'].values.astype('<S1').view(np.int8)
df[(a >= 97) & (a <= 122)]
302 µs ± 21.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%timeit df.col.str[0].isin(list(string.ascii_lowercase))
548 µs ± 13 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%timeit df[df.col.str.islower()]
559 µs ± 28.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

 %timeit df[df.col.str.match('[a-z].*')]
838 µs ± 17.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%timeit df[df.col.str[0]==df.col.str[0].str.lower()]
1.59 ms ± 65 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: Thanks for the timings! I've already upvoted yours, but it's cool (read:interesting) to see that `isin` here is actually outperforming the idiomatic `is_lower()` function.

Comment: @coldspeed yep. And funnily enough, `isin` works best with a list as arg instead of `set`. One of the great mysteries of pandas (I think `jpp` asked a question about this some while ago)

Answer (score 2):

If we're talking performance, how about NumPy? Convert the series to a string array, extract the first character and compare the ASCII value.

```
a = df['Names'].values.astype('<S1').view(np.int8)
df[(a >= 97) & (a <= 122)]

   col1 Names
0  1564  abby
```

If you need just the indices, use `np.nonzero`:

```
(a >= 97) & (a <= 122)
# array([ True, False])

np.flatnonzero((a >= 97) & (a <= 122))
# array([0])
```

Comment: Beautiful ;}.   .

Comment: @RafaelC Hey it'd be great if you can add the timings for mine and Wen's answer into yours too.

Comment: added the timings